# Finding the minimum and maxium price given utility index

Tags: utility, financial-economics

> Say you have the expected utility index $U(Y ) = \sqrt{Y}$ and an initial
>   wealth $Y = 10$. Consider the lottery with a payoff of $10$ with probability $\pi\in (0,1)$ and a payoff of $5$ with probability $1-\pi$ Note: Derive general expressions in $\pi$ and then use $\pi = 0.5$ to get specific answers.
>
> If you own this lottery, what is the minimum price and maximum price you would be willing to sell it for?

I am not sure how to proceed any suggestions are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a big fan of solving homework questions, but here is a hint:

Suppose you are selling the lottery for price $P$. Then your wealth would be $Y'=10+P$. You are looking for the minimum price $P$ such that 
$$U(10+P)  \geq \pi U(10+10)+(1-\pi)U(10+5).$$

Comment: I see so we are essentially solving for $P$ in the equation $$\sqrt{10+P} = \pi \sqrt{20} + (1-\pi)\sqrt{15}$$?